# Are these germanium diodes?

Tags: diodes

I searched with google images, guesses, every way I could. Is it a diode? Light bulb? The package says 2-0q0887.

The best I can figure it may be a germanium diode. An ohmmeter reads 00.0.

It is red on one end and purple on the other.

[image]

Comment: They look like fuses. 0 ohms is expected for an unblown fuse.

Comment: Unlikely diodes, as they don't have clearly visible polarity marking and their "legs" are equal length. Given the zero resistance (assuming you are measuring it correctly) and glass body, these might be fuses.

Comment: @winny shouldn't gas discharge tubes read infinite ohm with a normal (non high voltage) ohm meter?

Comment: @Arsenal Good catch! A fuse in non-standard size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are diodes, they will have a voltage drop in one direction across them. Put the meter in diode mode and measure (both ways) again. If you see a voltage while in diode mode in one direction, then it's a diode.

> The most significant difference between a silicon diode and a
> germanium diode is that silicon diodes have higher threshold voltage
> (typically 0.7 volts) and high thermal stability, whereas germanium
> diodes have lower threshold voltage (typically 0.3 volts) and lower
> thermal stability

Source: [Difference between Silicon Diode and Germanium Diode](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-silicon-diode-and-germanium-diode)

If it's not that then it's probably a fuse since it's reading 0 Ω. I have never measured a GDT directly but would think that it would read open and not 0 Ω (closed) since it's a voltage shunt device. Another thing it could be is a resistor, but that wouldn't make much sense as it should be more than 0 Ω. Bulbs also have resistance to them.

Answer (score 0):

The parts are likely to be fuses due to the 00.0 ohm. Also - the case is transparent as this will allow a visual indication if it is fused or not.